# Is it possible to use IS NOT NULL with a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql

I'm connecting to an Excel worksheet as a table using an OLEDB connector and running a query to extract the set of names that occur in the table.

When running a simple `SELECT * FROM table` query the connector returns a bunch of empty rows as well as the actual table information.

So I updated my query to:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name IS NOT NULL
```

Which gives me only the rows with data.
However `name` is not unique, to get the set of names that occur in the file I thought I could just add a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT name FROM table
WHERE name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY name
```

However this gives the error message:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'name IS NOT NULLGROUP BY name'.
```

I noticed that there is no space between NULL and GROUP BY, and thought perhaps I forgot to line-break. But it's properly separated by whitespace in the query...

Is it possible to use GROUP BY after a WHERE <> IS NOT NULL clause?
Is there some obvious bug in my code that I'm missing?

If I drop the `IS NOT NULL` clause and just use `GROUP BY` one of the resulting rows will be empty, so I still need the test that it's not NULL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `GROUP BY` after a `NULL`.  You would seem to have some erroneous characters there -- like not a real end-of-line.

One thing you can do is add an extra space -- just to be sure.  Here it is at the beginning of each line:

```
 SELECT name
 FROM table
 WHERE name IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY name
```